# Hacer funcionar crontab usando "notify"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, crontab

Explico el problema un poco por encima, pero básicamente es eso. Quiero añadir un script en crontab que se ejecute cada minuto. El script, por su parte, debe mostrar un sencillo mensaje de saludo. No tiene más.

Linea del crontab:

```
* * * * * sh /tmp/notify-test.sh
```

Según tengo entendido, eso ejecutaría mi "sh" cada minuto, ¿no?

Por otro lado, este es el script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/notify-send "Hola" "¿Qué tal?"
```

El comando de `notify-send` funciona correctamente en Terminal. Le añadí la ruta `/usr/bin/` porque había leído que tenía que introducir la ruta completa del comando. Usando el `whereis` encontré esa ruta.

Pasado el supuesto minuto, el syslog de Ubuntu me muestra `CMD (sh /tmp/notify-test.sh)`, ergo deduzco que lo ejecuta correctamente. ¿Está el problema en el contenido?

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto debería funcionarte (a mí me funcionó, [lo vi en Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111189/40596)):

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
XAUTHORITY=/home/<tu_usuario>/.Xauthority
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#               modifica esto
* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "hola"
```

Nótese además que estás diciendo:

```
* * * * * sh /tmp/notify-test.sh
```

Lo que hace esto es ejecutar el script con `sh`, en lugar del `bash` que seguramente quieres. Por tanto, deberías modificarlo a uno de estos:

- Indicar en el cronjob:

  ```
  * * * * * /bin/bash /tmp/notify-test.sh
  ```
- Hacer que el fichero sea ejecutable (`chmod +x notify-test.sh`) para que reconozca el binario con que ejecutarlo del shebang:

  ```
  * * * * * /tmp/notify-test.sh
  ```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero sigo un poco perdido. ¿Es lo mismo editar en consola con `crontab -e` que acceder a `/etc/crontab` con un editor cualquiera? Porque no me salen las mismas cosas. De hecho "syslog" solo recoge lo que edito en el primero.

Comment: @Viral editar en `/etc/crontab` está desaconsejadísimo. Por eso existe la funcionalidad `crontab` para hacer las ediciones correctamente. Escribe `crontab -l` para ver qué hay y `crontab -e` para editarlo.

Comment: @Viral y, en general, antes de lanzar cualquier script con `crontab`, valida dos cosas: que el script funcione solo correctamente y que crontab funcione. Para esto último, haz algo así como `* * * * * echo "hello" > /tmp/hola` y mira si escribe algo.

Comment: ¡Genial, ahora sí que funciona correctamente! Creo que lo mío no tiene caso. Estaba editando sobre /etc/crontab. Con `crontab -e` funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Viral ¡fantástico! En este mundo muchas cosas requieren práctica, ensayo y error :) Por cierto, me descubriste la utilidad `notify-send`, ¡qué buena!